# Play Framework 2.0: "Errorjava.lang.RuntimeException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

Xml Template:

```
@(product: models.Product, productComponents: List[models.ProductComponent])
<product>
  <name>@product.name</name>
  <tomcatLocation>@product.tomcatLocation</tomcatLocation>
  <productComponents>
    @for(productComponent <- productComponents) {
     <component>
       <name>@productComponent.name</name>
       <packageName>@productComponent.packageName</packageName>
       <buildPath>@productComponent.buildPath</buildPath>
       <packageFormat>@productComponent.packageFormat</packageFormat>
       <versionAction>@productComponent.versionAction</versionAction>
       <versionFilePath>@productComponent.versionFilePath</versionFilePath>
       <versionCommand>@productComponent.versionCommand</versionCommand>
     </component>
    }
  </productComponents>
</product>
```

Controller Action:

```
public static Result upgradeProduct(String serverId, String productId) throws InterruptedException
  {
      models.Server server = models.Server.retrieveById(Long.parseLong(serverId));
      models.Product product = models.Product.retrieveById(Long.parseLong(productId));

      List<models.ProductComponent> productComponents = 
              models.ProductComponent.retrieveByProductId(Long.parseLong(productId));

      Xml renderedXmlPage = upgradeService.render(product, productComponents);

      Promise<WS.Response> upgradeStatus = 
              WS.url("http://" + server.hostIp + ":8085/upgradeProduct").setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml").post(
                      renderedXmlPage.toString());

      String testMessage = upgradeStatus.get().getBody();

      return TODO;
  }
```

Web Service:

```
public static Result upgradeProduct()
{
  return async( WS.url(MAIN_URL).get().map(
          new Function<WS.Response, Result>() {
            public Result apply(WS.Response response)
            {
                try
                {
                    Document doc = response.asXml();
                    return ok("I WORKED");
                }
                catch(RuntimeException e)
                {
                    return ok("Error" + e.getMessage()+ "\n");
                }

            }
          })
        );
}
```

When I run this action, The following runtime exception is thrown

> "Errorjava.lang.RuntimeException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.".

The this exception is being thrown at "Document doc = response.asXml();". I don't know why this is occurring? any help is much appreciated thanks!

```
Stack Trace: 
play.libs.WS$Response.asXml(WS.java:332)
controllers.Service$1.apply(Service.java:40)
controllers.Service$1.apply(Service.java:35)
play.libs.F$Promise$2.apply(F.java:111)
play.api.libs.concurrent.STMPromise$$anonfun$map$1$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(Promise.scala:185)
scala.util.control.Exception$Catch$$anonfun$either$1.apply(Exception.scala:110)
scala.util.control.Exception$Catch$$anonfun$either$1.apply(Exception.scala:110)
scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:88)
scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.either(Exception.scala:110)
play.api.libs.concurrent.STMPromise.redeem(Promise.scala:166)
play.api.libs.concurrent.STMPromise$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Promise.scala:185)
play.api.libs.concurrent.STMPromise$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Promise.scala:184)
play.api.libs.concurrent.STMPromise$PromiseInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Promise.scala:10    4)
play.api.libs.concurrent.STMPromise$PromiseInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Promise.scala:10    3)
akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:290)
play.api.libs.concurrent.STMPromise$PromiseInvoker.apply(Promise.scala:101)
akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:617)
akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:179)
akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:161)
akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$MailboxExecutionTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:505)
akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:259)
akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:997)
akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1495)
akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
```

Comment: The error means, that the SAXParser gets a empty String to parse the XML. Please show the Stacktrace.

Comment: Stack Trace is added to question!

Comment: It Turns out the the response.body is an empty string. I am confused to way this is because looking at the http request. There is data in the body.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it doesn't look like you are returning your xml document from the service!? Instead you return "I WORKED", which of cause won't parse as xml, and the parser will throw an exception.

Comment: The Service is expected to return Content-Type text/plain. So there is no xml parsing for the response. I think it has to do with Document doc = response.asXml(); If I remove this line of code there is no runtime exception. and the service returns "I Worked"

Answer (score 0):

In the Service you are calling, via `WS`, an external URL (`MAIN_URL`) and using the response on line:

```
Document doc = response.asXml();
```

The error means that the service you are calling (`MAIN_URL`) is not returning XML.

By the way, your controller has `TODO` as return value, I'm not sure if that's what you want in there as it seems that you have working code in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the obvious case of not having any XML input to begin with, sometimes this error also gets thrown the second time your code tries to read a `javax.xml.transform.Source` or a `javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXSource`. The first time everything runs OK, but the second time the bytes have been consumed and you get that exception. At least that how I've encountered it, in which case I simply create the `Source` anew - I don't know applicable this is in your particular case.